Discovery in English law: is "train of inquiry" relevance too wide and subjective a test for relevance?
In English law, the test for relevance in discovery remains the Peruvian Guano test

"It seems to me that every document which relates to the matters in
question in the action, which not only would be evidence upon any
issue, but also which, it is reasonable to suppose, contains
information which may – not which must – either directly or
indirectly enable the party requiring the affidavit either to advance
his own case or to damage the case of his adversary if it is a document which may fairly lead him to a train of enquiry which may have either of those two consequences."

This is a very wide criterion, which can be interpreted differently by different lawyers.  Lawyer's judgment being as variable as human nature, there are bound to be different interpretations in practice on what this requirement means: especially on the "train of inquiry" kind of relevance.
Moreover, what passes between lawyers and clients on discovery obligations is covered by privilege, so there cannot be a systematic study on how lawyers advise clients in similar situations.
If this is right, is there any way to ensure the Peruvian Guano test is applied consistently by solicitors in practice?
How we can exclude the possibility (even probability) that, for the same clients on the same facts, one firm of solicitors advises disclosing 100 documents, whereas another advises disclosing only 10?
And if there is such a discrepancy, is it be unfair that some litigants are advise and do disclose a lot/less more than they would if they used another firm?
Please note that, from a practical perspective:

It is no answer that the other side has the option of taking out applications for further discovery etc.  They may or may not wish to do so due to concerns about costs.

Moreover, you can only apply for specific discovery if you can put forward grounds of believing that some "missing" document exists and is in the other side's possession.

This is practicable for documents that common sense suggests must exist (e.g. a medical chit if someone went to the A&E room), but does not cover many of the "train of inquiry" documents.


Putting the point differently:

would it not be better/clearer if the Law simply gets rid of the general discovery obligation with the Peruvian Guano test altogether, and replace it with

a Redfern Schedule style discovery (all relevant documents to be annexed to the Statement of Claim); and

while retaining a general civil and criminal obligation not to destroy relevant documents once a litigation has commenced?


While such a test would be more narrow, at least it is less subjective and one hopes leads to a more uniform result.

Law.SE is a place to get information about what the law is, not to solicit opinions on what it "should be".

Oh okay.  I can rephrase this entirely: does the Law + lawyer's duty to act in best interest of the client mandate a minimalist interpretation of the "train of inquiry" test.

I will mark my question answered.  Leave it to more experienced users to close this question, and I will entirely re-phrase and ask the question in terms of what the Law is.

Maybe
When the Peruvian Guano test was established in 1882, the number of documents producible in discovery was relatively small, and filing systems were based on physical files rather than virtual ones. You could literally go into a filing room and point to a small number of files and say, "These are relevant; nothing else is."
With the explosion of electronic documents and the decline in archival skills, relevant documents may be scattered across email systems, virtual drives, online messaging, text, etc., and they are unlikely to be properly archived - findable only by searching rather than by actually knowing where they are. Of course, an organisation cutting costs on archivists, thus making discovery hard, is not really an excuse.
However, Peruvian Guano hasn't been the test in most jurisdictions for more than 2 decades
australia
The test has been direct relevance. This was introduced following Lord Woolfe's review in England and Wales in 1996.

that the evidence could rationally affect (directly or indirectly) the assessment of the existence of a fact in issue in the proceeding


A majority of the High Court in BBH v The Queen (2012) 245 CLR 499 has endorsed the proposition that evidence is relevant and therefore admissible so long as it has probative value. This is so notwithstanding that it may ultimately be categorised by the tribunal of fact as carrying no weight: Heydon J at [97]–[104]; Crennan and Kiefel JJ at [152], [158]–[160]; Bell J at [194]–[197]. Moreover, the tribunal of fact is entitled to assess the particular piece of evidence by having regard to the whole of the evidence in the light of the issues at trial: Bell J at [196].

So, the premise of the question is flawed: a document is only relevant and therefore discoverable if it bears in some way on a fact that is in contention in the trial. Now, that's still a lot of documents, but that's because you seem to have the wrong end of the stick on relevance: its purpose is inclusionary, not exclusionary. That is, the purpose of the relevance rule is to alow material in, not to keep it out.
Arbitration is not Litigation
Redfern Schedules are often used in arbitration in an attempt to impose some restrictions on discovery. That's fine because arbitration is not litigation or criminal prosecution.

Arbitration is voluntary (at least, the parties agreed to arbitrate); court process involve coercion (at least on the defendant).
Arbitration settles private disputes; courts administer public justice.
The rules of an Arbitration are what the parties agree to and may or may not include rules of evidence; the rules of the court are imposed by the legislature and are not optional.
The primary purpose of an arbitration is to resolve a dispute; the primary purpose of litigation or prosecution is to render justice.

For these reasons, what is appropriate for one venue is not necessarily appropriate for another. In any event, for commercial litigants, they had their choice: they could have agreed to arbitrate.

These are really great points!

This resource also seems on point.

In other words, the relevance criterion can be wide, so long as there are other criteria, e.g. reasonable search, to ensure no practitioner/litigant is placed under a duty that is too onerous.  Esp. in the contemporary digital age with many more items that can be considered a "document".

This answers an earlier version of the question that asked "how to ensure the Peruvian Guano test is enforced consistently in practice." The question has since been edited in a way that may make this answer appear non-responsive.
canada
For specifics, you'd need to refer to particular rules of the court one is practicing in, but generally:

the opposing side can demand more disclosure if they believe disclosure is incomplete
the opposing party can apply for an order requiring that the producing party serve an affidavit certifying the completeness of the disclosure
inadequate disclosure may become apparent during discovery
in the extreme, inadequate disclosure may be grounds on which the judge could make an adverse inference against the party
inadequate disclosure can be grounds for special costs
failure to disclose a document prevents the holder of that document from making any use of it

It is an ethical obligation to instruct and supervise one's client as to the full scope of the disclosure obligations (Henriques v. Spraggs, 2008 BCCA 282, para. 7):

The order of discovery requires the client to give information in writing and on oath of all documents which are to have been in his corporeal possession or power, whether he is bound to produce them or not.  A client cannot be expected to realize the whole scope of that obligation without the aid and advice of his solicitor, who therefore has a peculiar duty in these matters as an officer of the court carefully to investigate the position and as far as possible see that the order is complied with.  A client left to himself could not know what is relevant, nor is he likely to realize that it is his obligation to disclose every relevant document, even a document which would establish, or go far to establish, against him his opponent’s case.  The solicitor cannot simply allow the client to make whatever affidavit of documents he thinks fit nor can he escape the responsibility of careful investigation or supervision.  If the client will not give him the information he is entitled to require or if he insists on swearing an affidavit which the solicitor knows to be imperfect or which he has every reason to think is imperfect, then the solicitor’s proper course is to withdraw from the case.  He does not discharge his duty in such a case by requesting the client to make a proper affidavit and then filing whatever affidavit the client thinks fit to swear to.

Note that some jurisdictions have enacted rules that reject the Peruvian Guano standard as the test of relevance for a party's primary disclosure obligations. For example, in British Columbia, the primary disclosure obligations are only to list "all documents that are or have been in the party's possession or control and that could, if available, be used by any party of record at trial to prove or disprove a material fact." The primary disclosure obligations no are longer are as broad as the "train-of-inquiry" analysis would have required. Only on application by the other party might broader production in line with the Peruvian Guano standard be ordered by the court. See Przybysz v. Crowe, 2011 BCSC 731, paras. 27-29.

Thanks for the answer, I have re-written the question title and body to make my point a bit clearer.

I don't think extreme cases are in issue.  Surely if you make a claim but do not put forward documents that obviously should exist (if your case is true), all reasonable judges / legal systems will take that against you.  The real problem comes with the wide and indeterminate "train of inquiry" relevance test.
